# How to remove a keyword in tridion core service?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

```
public void RemoveprimaryKey()
    {
        string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["domainName"];
        string userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["userName"];
        string passowrd = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["passowrd"];
        timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yy h:mm:ss tt").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "");
        string content = string.Empty;
        string primaryIndustry = "primaryIndustry";
        client = CoreServiceClientFactory.GetClient();
        string[] tcmList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "PrimaryIndustry.txt");
        string[] tcmSaved = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\log1\\" + "componentListsaved.txt");
        foreach (var tcmid in tcmList.Except(tcmSaved))
        {
            ComponentData ComponentContent = null;
            try
            {
                ComponentContent = client.Read(tcmid, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ComponentContent = null;
            }
            if (ComponentContent != null && ComponentContent.Content.Contains(primaryIndustry))
            {
                content = ComponentContent.Content;
                //content = content.Replace(subIndustry, secondaryIndustries);
                //content = content.Replace(primaryIndustry, null);
                // string str2 = content.Substring(content.IndexOf("<primaryIndustry"), content.IndexOf("</primaryIndustry>") - content.IndexOf("<primaryIndustry") + 18);

                //string result2 = str2.Remove(content.IndexOf("<primaryIndustry"), content.IndexOf("</primaryIndustry>"));
                string str1 = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("<primaryIndustry"));
                string str4 = content.Substring(0,content.IndexOf("</primaryIndustry"));
                content = str1 +  str4;
                ComponentContent.Content = content;
            }
```

here i need to remove Primary Industry tagged Keyword

Answer (score 1):

```
string str1= content.Remove(content.IndexOf("<primaryIndustry"), content.IndexOf("</primaryIndustry>") - content.IndexOf("<primaryIndustry") + 18);
string str = str1;
ComponentContent.Content = str;
```

*I tried on my own its working now i could able to remove keyword*

This might help some one.

Thanks